# Writing to textbox control from SerialDataReceivedEventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, static, controller

I'm pretty sure it's just me who is doing this the wrong way.

I've got `Form1` that has a button that onclick calls a method in my serialConn.cs called `connect()`.

```
public static bool connect(string comPort) {
        BTserial = new SerialPort(comPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        BTserial.Open();
        if (BTserial.IsOpen) {
            BTserial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEvent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

private static void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Data Incomming!");
        // Check if Chars are received
        if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Chars!");
            // Create new buffer
            byte[] ReadBuffer = new byte[BTserial.BytesToRead];

            // Read bytes from buffer
            BTserial.Read(ReadBuffer, 0, ReadBuffer.Length);
            BTserial.DiscardInBuffer();

            // Encode to string
            string data = bytesToString(ReadBuffer);

            ReadBuffer = null;
            data = null;
        }
    }
```

And thats all good, but when data is received, i want it printed in a `TextBox` controller in my `Form1`.. 
But since my `DataReceivedEvent()` is a `static` (and i guess i has to be?), i cant access anything?
So how would the best way to approach this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the Form instance to this connect method (from the buttons' event handler):

```
public class Form1 : Form {

  public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    serialConn.connect("the com port here", this);
  }

  // ... etc ...

}
```

while in serialConn:

```
public static bool connect(string comPort, Form1 whichForm) {
```

Then you could use a lambda function and close the "whichForm" reference inside of it like so:

But furthermore, you should make sure you don't actually modify the GUI from another thread other than the main one -- which is highly possible due to the nature of the SerialPort class which might very well raise the event from another background thread -- hence the this.Invoke( some other lambda ) which marshals that particular action which in turn gets executed on the main thread.

MSDN clearly states: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx

The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do the work on the proper thread.

```
public static bool connect(string comPort, Form1 whichForm) {
    BTserial = new SerialPort(comPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    BTserial.Open();
    if (BTserial.IsOpen) {
        BTserial.DataReceived += (sender, e) => {
          Debug.WriteLine("Data Incomming!");
          // Check if Chars are received
          if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars) {
              Debug.WriteLine("Chars!");
              // Create new buffer
              byte[] ReadBuffer = new byte[BTserial.BytesToRead];

              // Read bytes from buffer
              BTserial.Read(ReadBuffer, 0, ReadBuffer.Length);
              BTserial.DiscardInBuffer();

              // Encode to string
              string data = bytesToString(ReadBuffer);


              Action toBeRunOnGuiThread = () => whichForm.theTextBox.Text = data;

              // to guard yourself from all evil
              // you could check to see if it is needed to
              if (whichForm.InvokeRequired) 
                // marshal the call to the action all the way to the GUI thread
                whichForm.Invoke(toBeRunOnGuiThread);
              else
                // or, if we ARE on the GUI thread already, just call it from this thread
                toBeRunOnGuiThread();

              ReadBuffer = null;
              data = null;
          }
    };
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. i see the idea with running it inside the connect() method.
But dont understand: `Action toBeRunOnGuiThread = () => this.theTextBox.Text = data;
            this.Invoke(toBeRunOnGuiThread);` ... And i get syntaxt error on the `{` of `(sender, e) {` ('=>' expected)

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake I made earlier.. Have another look at the code.. I mistakenly thought the connect method was part of the Form1 class and that it was an instance method. Then I realized it is not part of that class, it belongs to serialConn and it is static. Try sending the Form instance (this) from within the buttons' click event handler to your connect method.

Comment: I reedited the whole post. By the Action toBeRunOnGuiThread I mean that the actual touching of the Form and thusly it's TextBox is not the end of your problem. You also need to perform the changing of the Text property in a very safe way. The SerialPort class runs commands on a background thread. In that way the user interface will never freeze. The user interface thread needs to be kept free of long jobs in order for it to process mouse clicks and what not. But all this comes with a price.You can't modify the user interface objects from background threads.You need to somehow send a message

Comment: Forgot to mention this.. So it was, indeed:         BTserial.DataReceived += (sender, e) => {
          Debug.WriteLine("Data Incomming!");
          // Check if Chars are received
          if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars) {
              Debug.WriteLine("Chars!");
              // Create new buffer  (dunno how I ate those up :))

Comment: Ahh i get it! and it works like a charm...
Just to clear up some things. `Lambda` means the way you took my datareceived method and put inside my connect right?

Comment: Lambda is, off ... if you want, you can befriend me on GTalk (look at my profile for the ID) :) --- and yes, that is Lambda for short. The fact that a method is not part of a class but rather resides inside another method. And by doing so it is allowed to harness all of the local variables (via "Closure") that are present in its nester method. By doing so we were able to send a Form instance all the way from within the OnClick event handler to this ... 3rd method. The only thing is that this 3rd method does not belong to any particular class you wrote and gets executed later on, ona dif thread

Comment: And, no, don't be preety sure that you're the only one. You're maybe one of the few of many (who didn't/don't know) who don't give up and who ask themselves questions (which aren't straightforward btw -- it's not an easy explanation). All of these being said it's a good question ! Upvote

Comment: And Lambda also includes the fact that a method has no name (it's anonymous). Lambdas are to delegates what 1, 2, 3 (literal constant integers) are to the int data type and "mom", "dad" (literal constant strings)are to the string data type. A delegate can point to null,it can point to a method(like you did with your += the static method)or it can point to a lambda,which is like a literal, constant, written write there on the spot.Delegates are pointers to methods(or annonymous methods).Once assigned, a delegate can be called and the corresponding method gets called.Events are delegate sets.

Comment: Thanks for a more in depth explanation! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24991/discussion-between-eduard-dumitru-and-christian-bekker)